# How to set hide while open a webpage

Tags: magento-1.9, php, javascript

While Opening a page, i need to set **hide** if i click then only it **shows toggle**. What i need to done?

**phtml**

```
<div class="navigation">
     <dt><?php echo $this->__($_filter->getName()) ?></dt>
     <dd><?php echo $_filter->getHtml() ?></dd>
</div>
```

**js**

```
 function glace_navigationlayer_filter_show(evt){
        var dt = Event.findElement(evt, 'dt');

        dt.next('dd').down('ol').toggle();
        dt.toggleClassName('glace_navigationlayer-collapsed'); 

        Event.stop(evt);
        return false;
  }
```

Comment: add `display:none;` directly in line or class or inline rest the toggle do the trick

Comment: Yes i tried if i add display none after that toggle not working

Comment: can you give me live i will check that

Comment: sorry it's a localhost

Comment: Check my updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will do trick for you

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery=$.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.navigation dd').hide(); 

    jQuery('.navigation dt').click(function(){ 
            jQuery(this).next('dd').slideToggle('slow');
            jQuery(this).toggleClass('glace_navigationlayer-collapsed'); 


        });


 }); 
</script>
```

Comment: I want to add a class because i need to add some css

Comment: add the class too...

Comment: TypeError: $.noConflict is not a function jQuery=$.noConflict();

Comment: did you added jquery library in that?

Comment: what library i need to add that

Comment: added that too try that and feedback

Comment: Okay but class not adding

Comment: updated check that

Comment: can you please check this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/109535/layer-navigation-problem