# Layer navigation problem

Tags: magento-1.9, php, javascript

```
<div class="navigation">
         <dt><?php echo $this->__($_filter->getName()) ?></dt>
         <dd><?php echo $_filter->getHtml() ?></dd>
    </div>
```

**Script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery=$.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.navigation dd').hide(); 

    jQuery('.navigation dt').hover(function(){ 
            jQuery(this).next('dd').slideToggle('slow');
            jQuery(this).toggleClass('glace_navigationlayer-collapsed'); 


        });


 }); 
</script>
```

If i goto dd it's automatically hide, entierely go out it should be hide
 what is the mistake i made here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below script may help you

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($){
     $(".block-layered-nav dt").click(function(){
     if($(this).next("dd").css("display") == "none"){
           $(this).next("dd").slideDown(200);
           $(this).removeClass("closed");
     } else {
           $(this).next("dd").slideUp(200);
           $(this).addClass("closed");
     }
     }); 
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: No luck it's not working

Comment: You can use click function like https://jsfiddle.net/pgsutariya/eq2vohfL/4/

Comment: here, once you hover dt it toggle dd but when you over hover state it will again hide dd

Comment: if click again then only it closed i need to close on leave that

Comment: then you have to add mouse.leave function() of jQuery

Comment: see, the link https://jsfiddle.net/pgsutariya/eq2vohfL/7/

Comment: Ok i will check but i need hover only

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37955/discussion-between-pg-sutariya-and-kothari).

Comment: Thanks it's working fine but i have a small problem

Comment: what problem? can you explain?

Comment: I have arrow mark if i hover i t will change it's working if i goto dd it change i want to change once entierely go out

Comment: You have add or remove class see the below link i am add class on hover yo dt and remove class on leave https://jsfiddle.net/pgsutariya/whzqjeuh/

Answer (score 2):

Use below code change class name as per your html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery = jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('#narrow-by-list dd').each(function(){ 
            jQuery(this).hide();

        });
        jQuery('#narrow-by-list dt').mouseover(function(e){ 
                jQuery('#narrow-by-list dd').each(function(){ 
                    if(jQuery(this).css("display") != "none"){
                        jQuery(this).slideUp('slow');
                    }
                });
                jQuery(this).next('dd').slideDown('slow');         
        });
     });
  </script>
```

Comment: No luck it's not working

Comment: check browser console.Is there any error post in question

Comment: No error on this

Comment: Updated answer check it.

Comment: if i go to dd it hide

Comment: Updated answer check it

Comment: Okay but after display it's not hide

Comment: Updated answer try it